# How to change the height of streamlit sidebar

Tags: css, streamlit

I tried couple of work arounds to change the height of streamlit sidebar using `css`. One of my approach is the code below but yet it does not solve my problem. I found some suggested approaches in [streamlit discussion forum](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/changing-height-width-of-st-sidebar-multiselect/17501) and those didn't help either. Can some one help?.

```py
import streamlit as st 


st.markdown(
    """
    <style>
    [data-testid="stSidebar"][aria-expanded="true"] > div:first-child {
        height: 80% ;
    }
    [data-testid="stSidebar"][aria-expanded="false"] > div:first-child {
        height: 80%
    }
    </style>
    """,
    unsafe_allow_html=True,
)


st.sidebar.markdown("Adjust sidebar height")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code to see if it solves your problem. I think it should. You have to pay close attention to the classes by using dev tools.

**Note:** by adding `!important` to your css rule will overwrite the default css. I think with this you should be good to go.

```py
import streamlit as st


st.markdown("""
    <style>
      section[data-testid="stSidebar"][aria-expanded="true"]{
        height: 80% !important;
      }
      section[data-testid="stSidebar"][aria-expanded="false"]{
        height: 80% !important;
      }
    </style>""", unsafe_allow_html=True)

st.sidebar.markdown("Adjust sidebar height")
```

output:
[image]